# Django Edit Form Secure Way

Tags: python, django

I have edit form (modelform) and for that form I created a url something like /contacts/edit//
My view is method base view and I am passing the contact_id from my template to the view as parameter.

Then that's what I am doing:

```
def edit_contact(request, contact_id):
    is_user_authenticated(request.user.is_authenticated)
    contact_person = get_object_or_404(domain.Contact.contacts, pk=contact_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ContactPersonForm(request.POST, instance=contact_person)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contacts/')
```

However that url can be reached by any user with just giving ID and basically you can edit any person you want.

I could do one more query to DB in order to find if a person is the right person to edit contact information but is that right way to do that? What's best practice for my situation?

Comment: If your request user is linked to the contact model, you want to edit, then you can remove `contact_id` param and always edit contacts for particular user.

Comment: it's indeed linked however there is more than 1 contact person for each user

Comment: Then just add a request user id in place where you getting contacts. Like `contact_person = get_object_or_404(domain.Contact.contacts, pk=contact_id, user=request.user)`

Comment: thanks. that helped now! and indeed exactly what I wanted.